# xdg-open fails to open file

Tags: xdg-open

I was trying to open an Excel file with python on Linux using xdg-open but realized xdg-open doesn't really work on my machine:

```
$ xdg-open ~/Documents/foo.xlsx 
/usr/bin/xdg-open: line 881: www-browser: command not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: line 881: links2: command not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: line 881: elinks: command not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: line 881: links: command not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: line 881: lynx: command not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: line 881: w3m: command not found
xdg-open: no method available for opening '/home/alex/Documents/foo.xlsx'
```

However, the MIME type appears to be properly set up:

```
$ xdg-mime query default $(xdg-mime query filetype ~/Documents/foo.xlsx)
libreoffice-calc.desktop
```

I can also open the file fine from file manager. From the error message above it looks like xdg-open thinks it's a URL and tries to pen it with a browser.

Do I need to configure xdg for xdg-open to work?

Comment: Ignore my last comment - I totally spaced on what you were actually trying to do. I just ran a test on my system and my LO spreadsheet was opened by a text editor (which I *did* select once in the File Manager to open a .cvs file, but not an .ods file).

Comment: It turned out xdg-open wasn't working because XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP variable wasn't set. And it only wasn't set in that specific shell I was using. Opening a new shell resolved the problem. What exactly unset XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP in that shell remains a mystery.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this working. I had to force a default in **$HOME/.config/mimetypes** and now `xdg-open filename.ods` works as expected:

```
xdg-mime default libreoffice-calc.desktop 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet'
```

So in your case, this should work for Excel files:

```
xdg-mime default libreoffice-calc.desktop 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
```